# Autofac Keyed Factory: Same Concrete Implementation For Different Enum Values

Tags: c#, autofac, factory

I want to create a field validator factory using autofac's built in IIndex<TKey, TValue> that will take in an enum value and return me an IFieldValidator.
My validation factory should either return a concrete implementation of FieldValidator or ConditionalFieldValidator based upon a supplied token type enum value.

```
Service
User
Candidate
Unknown
```

I want to return a ConditionalFieldValidator when the token type is `Service` and I want to return a FieldValidator when the token type is either `User, Candidate or Unknown`

It appears that ContainerBuilder's Keyed method only accepts one parameter which forces me to register the components like this:

```
builder.RegisterType<ConditionalFieldValidator>().Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.Service);
builder.RegisterType<FieldValidator>().Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.User);
builder.RegisterType<FieldValidator>().Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.Candidate);
builder.RegisterType<FieldValidator>().Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.Unknown);
```

Is there a better way to do this that doesn't duplicate the FieldValidator registration? Would be nice to be able to pass multiple token types to the Keyed method.

#### **EDIT**

I ended up creating an extension method that incorporates Alistair and Cyril's answers.

```
public static ContainerBuilder RegisterTypeKeyed<TConcrete, TAbstract>(this ContainerBuilder containerBuilder, params object[] values)
{
    var registration = containerBuilder.RegisterType<TConcrete>();
        
    foreach(var value in values)
        registration.Keyed<TAbstract>(value);

    return containerBuilder;
}
```

This allows you to register your keyed components in one line from your container factory.

```
builder.RegisterTypeKeyed<ConditionalFieldValidator, IFieldValidator>(AuthTokenType.Service);
builder.RegisterTypeKeyed<FieldValidator, IFieldValidator>(AuthTokenType.Candidate, AuthTokenType.Unknown, AuthTokenType.User);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to stack multiple `Keyed` calls onto the registration (like you can with `As<T>`), like so:

```
builder.RegisterType<FieldValidator>().Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.User)
                                      .Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.Candidate)
                                      .Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.Unknown);
```

That keeps the same registration of the `FieldValidator` **component** (including any instance sharing behaviour), but registers multiple **services**.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a component to more than one service

```
builder.RegisterType<FieldValidator>()
       .Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.User)
       .Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.Candidate)
       .Keyed<IFieldValidator>(TokenType.Unknown);
```

It will result in one registration with multiple associated service.